# host=$decideOnStartup not working in splunk configuration on Windows EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, splunk, aws-ssm

As [someone mentioned in the Splunk forum](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/Inputs-conf-decideonstartup/m-p/103954):

> $decideonstartup just would not work for me.

The [splunk daemon is *supposed*](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/Data/SetadefaulthostforaSplunkserver) to set the value automatically:

> Note: By default, the host attribute is set to the variable $decideOnStartup, which means that it's set to the hostname of the machine splunkd is running on. The splunk daemon re-interprets the value each time it starts up.

But it just stayed as `host=$decideonstartup` for me.

What's the best way to set this value when configuring Splunk via an AWS SSM Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [EC2 instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html):

```
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds" = "21600"} -Method PUT –Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token
$ip = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

And then you can insert the EC2 instance IP into the inputs.conf file `host=$ip`, assuming you're building the inputs.conf file within the SSM document.